# Java. Как конвертировать массив []String или []int в List<String> или List< Integer> соответственно?

Tags: java, массивы, коллекции

Как конвертировать массив `String[]` или `int[]` в `List<String>` или `List<Integer>` соответственно?  Я понимаю, как это сделать через циклы, но мне интересно знать, есть ли методы специальные для этого? Можно ли обойтись без циклов? Прошу пример привести.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Как уже сказано в соседнием ответе, для ссылочных типов можно использовать метод `Arrays.asList(array)`.

Для примитивов же придётся использовать циклы или Stream API. Например, для `int[] array` можно написать так:

```
List<Integer> list = IntStream.of(array).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Для `long[]` и `double[]` использовать соответственно `LongStream` и `DoubleStream`.

А, например, для `boolean[]` в любом случае нужно будет обойти массив - как-то так:

```
List<Boolean> list = 
    IntStream.range(0, array.length).mapToObj(i -> array[i])
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 3):

Для `String[]` можно поступить так:

```
List<> list = Arrays.asList(array);
```

Для перехода от `int[]` к `List<Integer>` можно использовать Stream API:

```
List<Integer> list2 = Arrays.stream(arr).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Да только вот это работает с String[], а вот если  List<Integer>number=Arrays.asList(array)  - работать не будет (  если учесть, что array - это int []array

Comment: @VaagnAkopyan справедливо. Дополнил ответ

Answer (score 3):

Дополню ещё одним способом для `int[]`, если есть в проекте библиотека [google guava](https://github.com/google/guava) то можно так:

```
List<Integer> list = Ints.asList(array);
```

Answer (score 0):

Если имеется массив объектов: `String[]`, `Integer[]`, `Double[]` и т. д., - тогда можно использовать метод [`Arrays.asList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList(T...)):

```java
String[] arr = {"1.4", "2.3", "3.2", "4.1"};

List<String> list = Arrays.asList(arr);
```

Если имеется массив примитивов: `int[]`, `long[]` или `double[]`, - тогда используем [`Arrays.stream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#stream-int:A-):

```java
int[] arr1 = {1, 2, 3, 4};
long[] arr2 = {1, 2, 3, 4};

List<Integer> list1 = Arrays.stream(arr1).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());
List<Long> list2 = Arrays.stream(arr2).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());
```