# Не получается преобразовать массив в лист и обратно

Tags: java

**Задача:**

Ввести 5 цифр, вывести их от большего к меньшему.

**Проблема:** В комментах я решил задачу через 2 for, но хотелось бы узнать как можно решить ее с помощью `Arrays.sort()` => преобразовать массив в лист => `Collections.reverse()` => преобразовать лист в массив и вывести всё. Потому что с этими махинациями массив-лист-массив вылетает ошибка.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        int[] array = new int[5];
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            array[i] = Integer.parseInt(reader.readLine());
        }
        sort(array);
        for (int x : array) {
            System.out.println(x);
        }
    }
    public static void sort(int[] array) {
        Arrays.sort(array);
    List<int[]> list = Arrays.asList(array);
    Collections.reverse(list);
    String[] array1 = list.toArray(new String[list.size()]);
       /* ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
        Arrays.sort(array);
        for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
            list.add(0, array[i]);
        }
        System.out.println(list.toString());
        for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
            array[i]=list.get(i);
        }
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));*/
    }
```

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayStoreException
>           at java.lang.System.arraycopy(Native Method)
>           at java.util.Arrays$ArrayList.toArray(Arrays.java:3833)
>           at com.javarush.task.task07.task0728.Solution.sort(Solution.java:29)
>           at com.javarush.task.task07.task0728.Solution.main(Solution.java:20)

Comment: Если у Вас java 8, то можно сделать так: `final List<Integer> list = Arrays.stream(array).boxed().sorted((i1, i2) -> {
   return i2 - i1;
  }).collect(Collectors.toList());`

Comment: вопрос ещё актуален, вставил код который предлагают выше, программа компилится, но данные не сортируются в обратную сторону.  Да и если честно, как-то заумно написано =(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот тут есть подробный разбор по Stream API и немного по тому как работают примитивы массивов.

[Java. Как конвертировать массив []String или []int в List<String> или List< Integer> соответственно?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/755521/java-%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B2-string-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-int-%D0%B2-liststring-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-list-inte)

Если ссылка сверху не помогла, можно сделать например String[] array; или Integer[] array;

Щас обновлю с кодом

UPD: (Тут вариант со String[] array;)
UPD2: (Скажите если тут ошибки при компиляции, код ручками с ноута =) )

```js
class test{
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{

BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

String[] array = new String[5];
for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
array[i] = reader.readLine();
                    }
sort(array);

for(String x : array){
System.out.println(x);
                      }
}
public static void sort(String[] array){
Arrays.sort(array);
List<String> l = Arrays.asList(array);
Collections.reverse(l);
}
}
```

Comment: Спасибо добрый человек, всё заработало) Сейчас еще почитаю по ссылке. Но я честно говоря в шоке =) у меня был код очень близкий к этому, но я даже не подозревал, что все дело в типе массива String. Просто когда я пытался что-то сделать с массивом типа int постоянно вылетала, то одна, то другая ошибка. Вот пришлось старым добрым for решать =)

Comment: Не за что ) Обращайтесь ) Еще с разные типы можете попробовать: еще Integer, если будет необходимо и другие, удачи в разработке )

Answer (score -1):

Во 2 строке функции sort вы создаёте

```
List<int[]> - коллекцию массивов
```

А вам нужна просто

```
List<int>
```

Comment: Генерик `List` не принимает примитивный тип `int`, как замена этому нужно испольтзовать `Integer`.

Comment: Точно, но все остальное можно оставить прежним.